# Failed to resolve: play-services-basement

Tags: android-studio, google-play-services

Hi i am using Android Studio 3.2.1. 
I just synced my application dependencies and suddenly i got below mentioned error. I have added and removed google dependencies, but no use. Any Help??

Failed to resolve: play-services-basement
"Open File"

Comment: Paste gradle code as well, and try using updated version of play services along with cache clear

Comment: Can you add any details like: code used, error problem encountered? [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) Show the community what you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

thanks for the reply, i have solved the issue by adding 
com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.0 and updating firebase messaging into com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.3.4. thanks